# How to define a derived property in object oriented Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

I want a read-only field that I can access as `fv=object.field`, but where the value that is
returned is computed from other fields of the object (i.e. the return value satisfies `fv==f(object.field2)`).

The desired functionality is the same as for the `property` function/decorator in Python.

I recall seeing a reference that this is possible by setting the  parameters of the `properties` block, but the Matlab OOP documentation is so scattered that I can't find it again.

Comment: "The desired functionality is the same as for the property function/decorator in Python."

Sounds like you should use Python.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I wish I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a "dependent" property.  A quick example of a class using a derived property is below:

```
classdef dependent_properties_example < handle       %Note: Deriving from handle is not required for this example.  It's just how I always use classes.
    properties (Dependent = true, SetAccess = private)
        derivedProp
    end
    properties (SetAccess = public, GetAccess = public)
        normalProp1 = 0;
        normalProp2 = 0;
    end
    methods
        function out = get.derivedProp(self)
            out = self.normalProp1 + self.normalProp2;
        end
    end
end
```

With this class defined, we can now run:

```
>> x = dependent_properties_example;
>> x.normalProp1 = 3;
>> x.normalProp2 = 10;
>> x
x = 
  dependent_properties_example handle

  Properties:
    derivedProp: 13
    normalProp1: 3
    normalProp2: 10
```

Comment: Is deriving from `handle` playing any special role here?  Is `get.name` syntax only allowed inside the `methods` block of a class?

Comment: No.  It's just how I always use classes.  The example given works either way.

Comment: Subclassing the `handle` class makes this distinct from a "value" class. Subclassing from `handle` yields object behavior that's more like what you'd see in other languages. The [MATLAB documentation on the difference between the two](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html) is quite helpful.

Comment: +1 I would have preferred giving an example of a class with properties like "firstName", "lastName" and a dependent property "name" that returns their combination. A bit more meaningful, at least to me :)

Comment: @DangKhoa: imho handle classes should have been the default behavior. I cant think of a single case where I wanted to have "value" class anyway...

Comment: @Amro  I agree on handle classes as the default.  Since I've trained my fingers to add "< handle", for me they are.  )

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property access methods: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html

To define get/set functions - the get function should allow you to return values computed from other members. The section "When to Use Set Methods with Dependent Properties" in the link above gives an example for this.